# Is there any Data Bus extensions for MassTransit

Tags: c#, servicebus, masstransit

Is there is any DataBus libraries that can plug on top of the MassTransit pipeline to allow sending of large payloads? Ideally I'd want to store these in MongoDb using their GridFS.

What I'm looking for is something similar to NServiceBus DataBus feature - http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/databus

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a similar feature in MassTransit, and is explained in this blog post:

http://blog.phatboyg.com/masstransit/2015/06/16/masstransit-v3-update.html

It's not in the documentation yet, but will be documented in a future update. The ability to encrypt the message data was added in v3.0.15 as well, and there are unit tests that show how it is done (yes, this too needs to be documented).

Comment: That's awesome I've been digging around in the code quite a lot recently and noticed that it wouldn't be that much hard work plumbing something in. It's great that its already baked in though!

Comment: We've decided to wrap this up with mongodb and make it public - https://github.com/LiberisLabs/MassTransit.MongoDb / https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.MessageData.MongoDb